# What's the syntax for literal arrays in Free Pascal?

Tags: arrays, literals, freepascal

There's a 50-odd hard-coded byte list I'd like to store in a byte array, but I can't find Free Pascal's syntax for hard-coded arrays.

Sets use `[elem, elem, elem]`, so what do arrays use?

Comment: Why can't you use a string for it?

Comment: The variable is a static key composed of bytes used in a simple encryption scheme. A string could suffice, but 1) every byte in the key would have to be escaped, and 2) using a byte array would reinforce the idea that the key is, in fact, a byre array.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try this

```
Const
  MyArray : Array[0..3] of byte= (0,1,2,3);
```

**UPDATE**

you must translate this

```
static int xlat[] = {
0x64, 0x73, 0x66, 0x64, 0x3b, 0x6b, 0x66, 0x6f,
0x41, 0x2c, 0x2e, 0x69, 0x79, 0x65, 0x77, 0x72,
0x6b, 0x6c, 0x64, 0x4a, 0x4b, 0x44, 0x48, 0x53,
0x55, 0x42, 0x73, 0x67, 0x76, 0x63, 0x61, 0x36,
0x39, 0x38, 0x33, 0x34, 0x6e, 0x63, 0x78, 0x76,
0x39, 0x38, 0x37, 0x33, 0x32, 0x35, 0x34, 0x6b,
0x3b, 0x66, 0x67, 0x38, 0x37
};

static int XLAT_SIZE = 53;
```

to this

```
const
 XLAT_SIZE = 53;
 xlat : Array[0..XLAT_SIZE-1] of Integer = (
 $64, $73, $66, $64, $3b, $6b, $66, $6f,
 $41, $2c, $2e, $69, $79, $65, $77, $72,
 $6b, $6c, $64, $4a, $4b, $44, $48, $53,
 $55, $42, $73, $67, $76, $63, $61, $36,
 $39, $38, $33, $34, $6e, $63, $78, $76,
 $39, $38, $37, $33, $32, $35, $34, $6b,
 $3b, $66, $67, $38, $37
);
```

Comment: The key is `xlat` in [ios7crypt.c](https://github.com/mcandre/ios7crypt/blob/master/ios7crypt.c) to be precise. Would the syntax be the same? When I copy your syntax, I get `Fatal: Syntax error, "," expected but ")" found`.

Comment: How can I concatenate two byte arrays?

Comment: 2.7.1 also support Delphi compat dynarray.create syntax.